# redirect 301 from underscore to hyphen

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am looking for the right syntax to replace a part of a URL with an underscore to a hyphen

The URL looks like this: www.test.com/variablepart/fixedpart_variablepart/
and I want it to be
www.test.com/variablepart/fixedpart-variablepart/

So I'm looking for fixedpart_ to be replaced with fixedpart-

I tried several things, eg. RewriteRule ^/fixedpart_?$ /fixedpart- [R=301,L]
but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^(variablepart/)(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make you can add this before all redirect rules.

Note: if you one underscore in rules and redirect to one hyphen. This is for reference.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```